# 'random_shuffle': is not a member of 'std' error

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to use [std::random_shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), and get a compilation error.

My compiler is v140(Visual Studio 2015), and I work on x64, Release mode.

#### My code:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
void foo()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

#### The errors which I get:

```
error C2039: 'random_shuffle': is not a member of 'std'
error C3861: 'random_shuffle': identifier not found
```

- Any idea what could the problem be?

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: @LogicStuff: That's already linked in the question.  What's your point?

Comment: I've never heard about the compiler "v140". I *guess* you mean Visual C++ version 14 (which came with Visual Studio 2015)?

Comment: @BenVoigt - The point is one should check their compiler flags. In particular the standard revision related ones.

Comment: @BenVoigt The point is that the specified page clearly states what he did wrong.

Comment: @m.rogalski: The specified page provides no clues at all what is wrong.  He's including the right header, he should have *a* `std::random_shuffle` even if his parameters aren't compatible.  I suspect corruption of the set of header files installed by the compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt - The page says "until C++17". So if one is compiling their code as C++17, it will result in the identifier not being defined in namesapce std. I'd say the page provides a pretty big clue.

Comment: @StoryTeller Does VS2015 support `C++17`?

Comment: @StoryTeller: It sure would be nice if that page said "removed in C++17".  What I see is "until C++17".  Either way, the toolchain isn't C++17.

Comment: I can not repeat this. Is this the full code required to produce the error? Can you add a main function and check that it alone causes the error?

Comment: @BenVoigt - Editorial notes about CPPReference aside (it says "until" for every removed feature), if the tool-chain isn't C++17 compatible, that is indeed a bug.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Another interesting thing  to note. [The official Visual Studio 2015 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt771443.aspx#random_shuffle) specifies that `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated and should not be used. The official recommendation is pretty much the answer bellow.

Comment: I can also make it compile with the same version of VS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code compiles fine with the default settings for toolchain v140. However, if you add the option `/std:c++latest`, removed parts of the standard library might not be usable anymore.

Probably an attempt to get as close as possible to C++17.

Comment: A conforming implementation is not allowed to remove deprecated parts of the standard library. It is allowed to remove parts that have been removed; deprecation is not removal.

Answer (score 38):

`random_shuffle` was deprecated in C++14 and completely removed in C++17.

You need to use `shuffle` which takes a random generator as parameter.

You can see a simple example on the site:

> ```
> std::random_device rd;
> std::mt19937 g(rd());
>
> std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
> ```

**[n4190](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4190.htm)**

> Removing auto_ptr, random_shuffle(), And Old  Stuff
>
> ...
>
> III. What Must Die
>
> D.12 "Random shuffle" [depr.alg.random.shuffle]
>
> This defines random_shuffle(first, last) and random_shuffle(first,
>   last, rng). (The latter takes a RandomNumberGenerator, whose
>   requirements are totally different from C++11's
>   UniformRandomNumberGenerator.)
>
> The problem with random_shuffle(first, last) is that it's permitted to
>   use rand(), which is permitted to be low quality.  (rand() is even
>   permitted to introduce data races, 26.8 [c.math]/5, although I'm not
>   aware of any implementation that does so.)  Constructing mt19937 urng
>   and calling shuffle(first, last, urng) is a far superior alternative. 
>   Unlike random_shuffle(first, last), calling shuffle(first, last, urng)
>   requires the user to be aware of the URNG's existence and state, but I
>   argue that this is a feature, not a bug.
>
> random_shuffle(first, last, rng) is the Knuth shuffle algorithm. It's
>   not evil, but it's almost unusable in practice, because the "rng"
>   function object is required to provide a very strange interface. (It's
>   actually required to return a uniform integer distribution over a
>   varying interval, which is difficult to do without introducing bias.)
>   shuffle(first, last, urng) is vastly easier to use, because it
>   directly consumes a URNG.

---

### Visual Studio C++ standard version.

Unlike `gcc` or `clang`, Visual Studio doesn't offer the option to select the standard version, so the question that pops up is: **which C++ standard does VS implement?** The answer is... neither... and a little of every. Last I checked their philosophy was that they strive to slowly get to the latest standard version, but not in standard versions steps, that is they were implementing C++14 features while C+11 wasn't still fully implemented. So you will see some parts of C++11 implemented, some parts of C++14 implemented and some parts of C++17 implemented.

Comment: That's not an example of `std::random_shuffle`, and the compile error he's getting is not consistent with passing the wrong number of parameters.

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you. Investigating if the 2 param `random_shuffle` is deprecated of removed.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: @Galik Q: "I get error: 'random_shuffle': is not a member of 'std'" A: "`random_shuffle` was removed" How does that not answer the question?

Comment: @bolov `random_shuffle` was not, to my knowledge, removed from `VS2015` and has not been removed from current version of the `C++` standard.

Comment: @bolov The fact is some people still use that function and although it is good to educate people of the need to migrate to the new version such advice is the answer to a different question.

Comment: @Galik I provided quotes from an official document stating that `random_shuffle` is to be removed in `C++17`

Comment: @bolov No one has ever disputed that. This question has nothing whatsoever to do with `C++17`

Comment: @Galik how is this not related with `c++17`? Fact1: OP gets error in Visual Studio about a function not found in `std`. Fact2: said function is removed in `C++17`. Fact3: Visual Studio is implementing features of C++17.

Comment: #include <random>

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR:

I was in Visual Studio and faced this error.
To fix this, simply set the `/Zc:__cplusplus` flag in `Properties > C/C++ > Command Line` and you are good to go.

### Long Explanation:

I faced this issue when trying to use [Hayai](https://github.com/nickbruun/hayai). In visual studio the `__cplusplus` is always set as `199711L` and `Hayai` that also checks for this always fails in visual studio becasue of this:

```cpp
        /// Randomly shuffles the order of tests.
        static void ShuffleTests()
        {
            Benchmarker& instance = Instance();
#if __cplusplus > 201100L
            std::random_device rd;
            std::mt19937 g(rd());
            std::shuffle(instance._tests.begin(),
                         instance._tests.end(),
                         g);
#else
            std::random_shuffle(instance._tests.begin(),
                                instance._tests.end());
#endif
        }
```

As you can see becasue of this issue in visual studio it always branches into the wrong snippet and thus fail.
To fix this, simply set the `/Zc:__cplusplus` flag in `Properties > C/C++ > Command Line` and you are good to go.

From Microsoft:

> The `/Zc:__cplusplus` compiler option enables the __cplusplus
> preprocessor macro to report an updated value for recent C++ language
> standards support. By default, Visual Studio always returns the value
> "199711L" for the `__cplusplus` preprocessor macro.
>
> Remarks
>
> ---
>
> The `__cplusplus` preprocessor macro is commonly used to report support
> for a particular version of the C++ standard. Because lots of existing
> code appears to depend on the value of this macro matching "199711L",
> the compiler does not change the value of the macro unless you
> explicitly opt-in by using the `/Zc:__cplusplus` compiler option. The
> `/Zc:__cplusplus` option is available starting in Visual Studio 2017
> version 15.7, and is off by default. In earlier versions of Visual
> Studio, and by default, or if `/Zc:__cplusplus`- is specified, Visual
> Studio returns the value "199711L" for the __cplusplus preprocessor
> macro. The `/permissive`- option does not enable `/Zc:__cplusplus`.
>
> When the `/Zc:__cplusplus` option is enabled, the value reported by the
> `__cplusplus` macro depends on the `/std` version switch setting. This table shows the possible values for the macro:

Make sure to read the actual article [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=vs-2019)